# Get Path of the document from IWpfTextView for non cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I want to add some buttons to the text editor in VS. In the ViewPortTextViewCreationListener when ViewPort manager is created I would like to know the path of the document or it

```
public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView) {
    var result = _textDocumentFactoryService.TryGetTextDocument(TextView.TextBuffer, out ITextDocument textDocument);
    new ViewPortSwitcher(textView);
}
```

I've tried to use `ITextDocumentFactoryService` to get `ITextDocument` from TextBuffer (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915010/get-the-current-filename-from-a-visual-studio-text-adornment-extension)). If I open cs file it works properly. But if I open cshtml file TryGetTextDocument returns false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution [see MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bae85815-0499-45b9-a5f0-8cad8139ec37/get-the-itextbuffer-from-the-project-item?forum=vseditor):

```
public static string GetPath(this IWpfTextView textView) {
    textView.TextBuffer.Properties.TryGetProperty(typeof(IVsTextBuffer), out IVsTextBuffer bufferAdapter);
    var persistFileFormat = bufferAdapter as IPersistFileFormat;

    if (persistFileFormat == null) {
        return null;
    }
    persistFileFormat.GetCurFile(out string filePath, out _);
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer. So it could help other community members who get the same issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I cannot mark it within two days after posting the question.